# What is the purpose of usb0 ethernet device on Centos 6.5 machine?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ethernet

My Centos 6.5 machine installed with 2 ethernet device (eth0 and eth1).
But when I listed all ethernet device with ifconfig -a as root, in resulted list have another ethernet device usb0, as follow:

```
usb0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:40:B5:87:34:8C
      inet addr:169.254.95.120  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3440:b5ff:fe87:348c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1716 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:238284 (232.6 KiB)  TX bytes:230702 (225.2 KiB)
```

AFAIK, I never configure it. My Question is, What are the purpose of usb0 ethernet device on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's for TCP/IP communications over USB. Why you would want to do this varies, but usually it's because a specific device requires it. Some notable examples are the BeagleBone, USB tethering with modern Linux kernel based phones, and *possibly* some amateur radio devices utilizing USB (likely for packet radio).

To the best of my knowledge, usb0 is enabled and configured automatically on many Linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

This is an In-Band management port.  IBM, among others, use a lights-out management port.  On the back of the machine, it may be called IMM or Service, with a normal ethernet port there.  That goes to a small, single-board computer that manages power, serial console, etc.  There's a small web server embedded.

The usb0 interface on the is ethernet-over-USB from the IMM to the host.  This way, the host OS can contact the IMM and perform configuration and/or management.